# Corrupted excel files are zero-byted

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, hexadecimal

We have an issue at work with specific Excel files which seem to have been tampered with.
Well, those Excel files are stored in a folder which is accessible on the work network.
We are not sure about the real culprit of the corruption.

So, what happened to the files is that something renamed them in hexadecimal, and they all have a size of 0 byte without an extension name.

We tried the usual recovery method with the restore function from Excel. We are using the 2013 version. Fact is that there is the autosave and the computer hosting the files was turned on for all the weekend, so the saving feature may have run with the corrupt files.

So this is what the files should look like:
[Excel files are correctly ordered with their sizes and extension.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xru9J.png)

And this is what they look like after the corruption: [Excel files are renamed in hexadecimal, and weight 0 byte each without an extension.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9cVr.png)

It looks like the original files were wiped, and replaced by those.
The antivirus used by the host computer is Smadav or so. It is not usually connected to the internet. We are using macros in our workbooks.

Comment: Is there a virus in the computer? Try to scan with antivirus software.

Comment: I am planning to have a deep scan this weekend. I am suspecting everything right now, but after the scan, things should be cleared.

Comment: I ran Kaspersky virus removal tool. There is nothing besides the adware which was a few only.

Comment: I have made peace with the fact that the files are certainly lost. We will just redo the work.